# PhpStorm keeps opening default macOS terminal

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, settings

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this but I need some help setting up the terminal in PhpStorm...

I recently switched to macOS (before that I was a Windows user) and installed PhpStorm and set everything up as I wanted except I ran into a small problem that is not really a problem but more of an inconvenience...

Every time I open the terminal in PhpStorm it opens the macOS terminal but I want to use the one in the IDE.

What settings do I have to change or where have I messed up that this is happening?

Those are the settings in PhpStorm:
[image]

P.S. Sorry for bad English it is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `Shell path` back to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Will I be able to use git comands and macOS comands both in that terminal?

Comment: true.. well i'll give it a try then :)